# Are the long-lasting effects of prestidigation magical?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Obviously the *casting* is magical, but are the lasting results themselves magical, and in particular do they trigger Detect Magic?

Specifically, supposing that I

> make a color, a small mark, or a symbol appear on an object or a surface for 1 hour.

on someone's chest, and then 5 minutes later that person meets a wizard who has Detect Magic running.

Does the wizard get a ping on their Detect Magic, from the symbol?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Yes, they are magical.

To determine if something is magical, we can consult the *Sage Advice Compendium*:

> Determining whether a game feature is magical is straightforward. Ask yourself these questions about the feature:
>
> - Is it a magic item?
> - Is it a spell? Or does it let you create the effects of a spell that’s mentioned in its description?
> - Is it a spell attack?
> - Is it fueled by the use of spell slots?
> - Does its description say it’s magical?
>
> If your answer to any of those questions is yes, the feature is magical.

The relevant question for us is "is it a spell?", and since *prestidigitation* is a spell, its effects are magical. This is confirmed by the spell description:

> You create one of the following *magical* effects within range

The effects of a spell are magical unless explicitly stated otherwise, as in the trinkets created by *prestidigitation*:

> You create a *nonmagical* trinket

Because *prestidigitation* is a spell, and because it says it creates magical effects, the following effect is magical and will be detected as such by *detect magic*:

> You make a color, a small mark, or a symbol appear on an object or a surface for 1 hour.

Comment: I think you should also note that *Prestidigitation* does indeed have a listed duration of 1 hour, which is important because it means that all the non-instantaneous effects happen within the spell's duration. That sidesteps the ambiguity over whether effects that persist after the duration of the spell are still magical. (Though in this case the fact that the description explicitly calls out the effects as magical would probably resolve that ambiguity.)